# Can't method chain with async/await

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, async-await

I have an ASP.NET app running on .NET 4.6.1.

I can't use `.Sum()` on my awaited `GetInts()` result. The compiler thinks that `GetInts()` is a task. `SumIntsOneLinerBroker()` doesn't compile.

```
public Task<List<int>> GetInts() {
    var list = new List<int> { 4, 5 };

    return Task.FromResult(list);
}

public async Task<int> SumInts() {
    var ints = await GetInts();
    return ints.Sum();
}

public async Task<int> SumIntsOneLinerBroker() {
    return await GetInts().Sum();
}

public async Task<int> SumIntsOneLinerWorking() {
    return (await GetInts()).Sum();
}
```

Comment: The parentheses is how this has always worked

Comment: I'll take your word for it, thanks. Marking this as closed.

Comment: *don't* post code as screenshots. Please simply copy&paste it. That way search engines can index your post, other people can find it through the search, people can copy&paste the code, it uses less traffic, the list goes on and on. Thanks!

Comment: @DJKempner - Please don't post screenshots - we need a [mcve] so that we can run your code and give you a decent answer. Please post the code as text.

Comment: If you don't use parentheses, your await is defined as `await (GetInts().Sum())`, which of course can't compile

Comment: Thanks @LonelyNeuron, I dropped in the source code.

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity, I dropped in the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways of handling this. The most common is probably the parentheses that you show in your code and confirmed by Marc.

An alternative is [`.ContinueWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405(v=vs.110).aspx) which lets you pass the result of the first operation to the second. Here's a [Microsoft Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537612(v=vs.110).aspx). Keep in mind, when you utilize `ContinueWith`, exceptions will get wrapped in an `AggregateException`, which can alter your exception handling.

Answer (score -1):

Confirmed by Marc, the parentheses enclosing method as seen in the second image is the proper approach. Nothing to see here.